# What does the word "quips" mean here?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Here is a sentence from a video editor's description:

> The editor adds all your notes to your video clips, which enables you to search within the editor to easily find a particular video clip or organize related quips.

I know the lexical meanings of the word ["quips"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quip), but they don't seem to fit here.

Please see the phrase "related quips" [here](http://patterntap.com/quips/1812). It is not used in any of the senses mentioned on the linked dictionary. Maybe this is a new usage that is yet to gain acceptance from English speakers.

The text mentions the app's ability to put director's or crew's notes in one place and make everything searchable and systematic. The focus is on its usability in a film's production process. The app adds all types of metadata to video clips.

Comment: I'd say it's a typo...

Comment: I agree it's a typo.  It should be "clips" not "quips".

Comment: I've removed the description of another software package. Thatt quote did not use the term "quips"  and seemed to be completely irrelevant